# Is Google Native Client expected to have Mozilla's and Microsoft's support?

Tags: web-applications, standards, google-nativeclient

Personally I think that Google Native Client is an amazing technology, but has no future without the support from major browsers.

- Is Native Client expected to be standardized, just like HTML?
- Would major organisations like Microsoft and Mozilla (expected to) support it, or only Chrome will support it?
- Is there any chance one day we could develop cross browser, no plugins web apps with Native Client, along with HTML5?

Comment: Sure they will! Of course, Microsoft will have to be dragged kicking and screaming..

Answer (score 4):

I think you'll want to see the following page, which [explains native client](http://nativeclient.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/what-is-native-client/)

What you'll want to read is the comments of that page.

Short answer, yes, nacl team hope to at least get Firefox support as a plugin, if not more than that...

Comment: Good link :) I expect that all open source, community driven browsers adopt Nacl pretty fast, closed source, commercial browser will try to not use it but will adopt it at the end

Answer (score 1):

If Native Client is successful, which I think will happen on android tablets and chrome os first, then FireFox and Safari (iPad!) will probably implement it and MS could eventually be forced into adding it for IE.

Google has open sourced the plug-in so it should be portable to other browsers.  It could feasibly be installed as a plug-in to other browsers just like flash is installed.

**So, YES, there is a very good chance!**

Answer (score 1):

Native client can be added to other browsers by downloading Google Chrome Frame.

The EXE Installer is at
[chromeframe](http://www.google.com/chromeframe)
and the MSI enterprise installer (for windows domains) is at
[MSI Installer](http://www.google.com/chromeframe/eula.html?msi=true)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this exactly answers your question, but there is [Emscripten](http://www.emscripten.org/) which is by Alon Zakai who works as an employee at Mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

With the new Metro style app model from Microsoft fully endorsing web and javascript, it will be interesting to see if something like Native Client will stick.